# Heroku dockerfile rm command doesn't work

Tags: heroku-cli

when I build an app with docker the command

```
RUN rm -f something.txt
```

in Dockerfile
works fine but using the same command with heroku (heroku container:push web -a ...)
doesn't actually delete the file. No error is produced anyway.
Any solution
Thanks

PS: I also tried RUN shred -u something.txt same issue

Comment: I have the same exact issue. Nice to know its not just me. Too bad this never got a response.